# is the preimage of a free product of groups itself a free product

Tags: group-theory, free-product

I have an epimorphism of groups $f:G\to H*K$. Is it true that $G=H'*K'$ for the preimages $H'=f^{-1}(H)$ and $K'=f^{-1}(K)$?

UPDATE: (after Tsemo's answer)
I have a group $G$ generated by two of its subgroups: $G=\langle H',K'\rangle$, and an epimorphism of $G$ onto a free product of two groups: $f:G\to H*K$. Under this epimorphism $f$, $H'$ and $K'$ map isomorphically onto $H$ and $K$ respectively. Is it true then, that $G=H'*K'$?

Comment: The proper thing to do, after a good answer has been given to your question, such as the answer of @TsemoAristide, is to accept the answer. Then it is certainly ok to ask a followup question, using the knowledge you have gained from that answer. However, to change your question after a good answer has been given is rather impolite to the person who wrote that answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher thank you for your comment. I thought that the spirit here is less formal than that. Will be more attentive in future.

Comment: What's true, however, is that if a 2-generated group $G$ admits an epimorphism to $Z\star Z$, then $G$ itself is free of rank 2.

Comment: No: for instance, the direct product of a (nontrivial) free product with a nontrivial group has no nontrivial free product decomposition. On the other hand, it's an amalgam (more generally taking inverses images in surjective group homomorphism, one pulls back amalgam decompositions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, take the product of a free group $G$ which $H$ which is not free and the projection onto $G$.

Let $g\in Ker f$, $g=h_1k_1h_2k_2...h_nk_n, h_i\in H, k_i\in K$, $f(g)=f(h_1)f(k_1)..f(h_n)f(k_n)=1$ where $f(h_i)\in H, f(k_i)\in K$, since $H*K$ is a free product, $f(h_i)=f(k_i)=1$ and $h_i=k_i=1$ since the restrictions of $f$ to $H'$ and $K'$ are injective.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You helped me state my question more clearly. Could you look at the update, please?

Comment: Thanks again! So your update shows that the new statement of the question has answer yes.